# pandas concat ValueError - passed values do not match implied by indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to concatenate 2 series into a dataframe like this

```
c_dist_df = pd.concat([d.value_counts(), v.value_counts()], axis=1, sort=True)
```

and I get the error -

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 7), indices imply (2, 5)

This is what my input `series` look like -

```
d.value_counts()
(-0.001, 8.0]     2121
(127.0, 215.0]    2017
(36.0, 127.0]     2006
(215.0, 695.0]    2003
(8.0, 36.0]       1914
Name: X, dtype: int64

v.value_counts()
(215.0, 695.0]    204
(36.0, 127.0]     204
(127.0, 215.0]    202
(-0.001, 8.0]     196
(8.0, 36.0]       177
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

The shapes and the index values are the same -

```
np.shape(d.value_counts()) //returns (5,)
np.shape(v.value_counts()) //returns (5,)
```

I am unable to figure out how is the shape of passed values (2, 7). Can someone help?

I am using `Python version 3.7.0` and `Pandas version 0.23.4`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? I tried your code on 2 random series and it works fine.

Comment: The data in the question is the actual data I am working with. If it helps, the index of the series is of `pandas.interval` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `join_axes` parameter. Try:

```
d_val = d.value_counts()
v_val = v.value_counts()

pd.concat([d_val, v_val], axis=1, join_axes=[d_val.index], sort=True)
```

Some other alternatives:

1. Use `join` instead of `concat`. But since `join` can only be used on dataframes you will have to convert both your series into dataframes before joining.

   ```
   d_val.to_frame(name='d_vc').join(v_val.to_frame(name='v_vc'))
   ```
2. Assign both series as columns while initializing the dataframe:

   ```
   pd.DataFrame(dict(d_vc = d_val, v_vc = v_val)).reset_index()
   ```

Comment: thanks for your response - however, both solutions are not working. However, I can get them to join by `reset_index` before the merge - i.e. `pd.DataFrame(dict(d_vc = d_val.reset_index(), v_vc = v_val.reset_index()))`